# paper-elements not loading with Polymer 1.0

Tags: html, polymer, bower

I am new to web dev in general, so please be gentle.

Whenever I try to link a paper element into my html

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
```

i get the error:

`Uncaught Element name could not be inferred.`

In the JS console of Chromium (37.0.2062.120).

my bower.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "homepage": "",
  "authors": [
    "crodgers"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "core-ajax": "Polymer/core-ajax#~0.5.6",
    "core-menu": "Polymer/core-menu#~0.5.6",
    "core-scaffold": "Polymer/core-scaffold#~0.5.6",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#~1.0.5",
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#1.1.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webcomponentsjs": "0.7.12",
    "polymer": "^0.5"
  }
}
```

If I remove the links to paper elements, the page loads as expected. Adding any link to a paper elemtent, regardless of use in the doc, causes this error to show once for each attempted link.

Google search has yielded very little for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neil John Ramal is right. However, your problem remains even when you removed the core elements because of the `resolutions` in your bower.json. The core and the paper elements require two different version of Polymer. The core elements require 0.5 and the paper ones 1.0. The resolution tells bower to get Polymer 0.5.
Even when you removed the core elements you still had an old version of Polymer.
 So in addition to removing the core elements from your bower.json, also remove the whole resolution block. To be on the save side, I would delete the bower directory and re-run bower install.

Comment: Turns out the core elements were not brought up to 1.0. app-template-layout is the new way, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use Polymer 1.1.0 but you are also using core elements from 0.5. **They are not compatible.** Try to remove them from your bower directory.

Comment: The core elements are working fine. I have a core-scaffold and a core-menu running in the page. The errors only show up when i try to link in a paper element.

I tried removing the core element links from the page and adding back in a paper-card. The error is still present.